# Looking for a report that can be emailed for an automated testing suite run on WebdriverIO Selenium in Jenkins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins, automated-tests, report, webdriver-io

I have a local suite of automated tests I'm running on a local Jenkins instance.
I want to output an automated report of the builds that can be attached to emails in Jenkins.
Allure Reporting won't work as the Jenkins server is not publicly accessible.

I've tried HTML Reporter plugins on Jenkins but have had no luck.
Json reporter also has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use allure reports. Have the Allure Report plugin on Jenkins generate the report. Once the report is generated you zip the folder containing the report. You can write a small script in the post-build steps for this.

Next, you have to use the editable email notification plugin on Jenkins and configure it to send attachments in the post-build actions of your job configuration. Select the path of the zip file here.